# account balance

Tags: vba

how to calculate account balance using vb 6.0 and access dbase
example :

```
January 2000   2500.00
Febuary 2000   2300.00
```

when user choose January 2000, it will display 2500.00 and when user choose Febuary 2000 it will display 4800.00.

Hope anyone can help me
Thanks

```
Dim TOTAL, FMACT As Double 
TOTAL = 0 
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset 

With rs2 
    .Open "SELECT * FROM SW WHERE dtaYear=" & cmbYear.Text & " ", Con, 1, 2 
    Let FMACT = rs2![SWACTFM] 

    If .RecordCount > 0 Then 
        TOTAL = TOTAL + FMACT 
        .MoveFirst 

        Do While rs2.EOF = True 
            .MoveNext 
            ExcelWS.Cells(6, 7) = TOTAL 
        Loop 
    End If 

   .Close 
   Set rs2 = Nothing 
End With
```

Comment: what is the format of your value? is it a string?

Comment: Where would we begin to try to help you w/that minimalist description?

Comment: Please do attempt before come to here. If you get any errors or technical difficulties ,we will help you sure.

Comment: Dim TOTAL, FMACT As Double
TOTAL = 0
            Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
            With rs2
            .Open "SELECT * FROM SW WHERE  dtaYear=" & cmbYear.Text & " ", Con, 1, 2
         Let FMACT = rs2![SWACTFM]
            If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            
         TOTAL = TOTAL + FMACT
            .MoveFirst
           
             Do While rs2.EOF = True
             .MoveNext
              ExcelWS.Cells(6, 7) = TOTAL
             Loop
            End If
            .Close
            Set rs2 = Nothing
            End With

Comment: example of code that i have write

Answer (score 0):

there are some problem with your code

1. Since Total is outside the `Do While` loop, it is not accumulating
2. `.MoveNext` should be execute after `ExcelWS.Cells(6,7) = TOTAL`, otherwise you will miss the first record

I am not sure what do you want, seems you don't need while loop here if you want to fetch only one record from database each time. you can try this.

```
Private Total As Double
Total = 0

Private Sub Cal_Total()
    Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset 

    With rs2 
        .Open "SELECT * FROM SW WHERE dtaYear=" & cmbYear.Text & " ", Con, 1, 2 

        .MoveFirst
        If .RecordCount > 0 Then 
            Do While rs2.EOF = False 
                Total = Total + rs2![SWACTFM]
                .MoveNext
            Loop

            ExcelWS.Cells(6,7) = Total
        End If 

       .Close 
       Set rs2 = Nothing 
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, nick i want to accumulate total balance. for example when user choose January 2000 it will display balance for January 2000 but when user choose Febuary 2000, it will display (total balance for January + total balance Febuary)

Comment: I have changed the code so the Total will be accumulated. You need to declare the Total and set it to 0 outsize the function, otherwise the total will always start from 0 when you call this function

Comment: By the way, instead of using total, you can get the value from `ExcelWS.Cell(6,7)` every time you call the function, so the cell will always accumulate the balance

Comment: ok, may i know what is different between  Do While rs2.EOF = True and  Do While rs2.EOF = False

Comment: `Do while rs2.EOF = False` means keep looping if the recordset is NOT end of file, so the loop will be finished once the rs2 is EOF = true. I will update my answer seems it is incorrect

Comment: your code is ok but when i choose January 2000, it give me total for January 2000 and Febuary 2000. What i want is when i choose  January 2000 it will display balance for January 2000 but when i choose Febuary 2000, it will display (total balance for January + total balance Febuary). Thanks n sorry

Comment: well, what my query does is accumulating the total balance every time your call the function, therefore if you choose January 2000 firstly, it will display the balance of Jan 2000. Then if you choose Feb 2000, then it will get the total balance of Jan 2000 and Feb 2000. If you choose Jan 2000 again, the function will give you total of Jan 2000 + Feb 2000 + Jan 2000. In this case, I would recommend you change your query, so it will return you both Jan 2000 and Feb 2000 records if you choose Feb 2000.

Comment: By the way, if you can have a separate field in database for year and month (would be better using a numeric month value rather than a string), then your issue can be fixed by a seconds.